# Wildfly deploys non-war extension files without any error, but accessing the application in the browser gives a 404 Page Not Found

Tags: java, testing, deployment, war, wildfly-8

I'm learning web application development and deployment, using NetBeans and Wildfly 8.2.0. I was curious as to how a web application is deployed, and decided to play around to satisfy my curiosity.

I created a demo eCommerce JSF app with an eCommerce.war file, and deployed it using Wildfly's admin panel. It worked without any errors. Then, I changed the name & extension of eCommerce.war to testCommerce.abc and tried deploying it. And although not a .war extension, or .jar or .ear for that matter, it deployed succesfully, but I got a 404 when I tried to access it in the browser. I disabled the eCommerce.war app from the Admin Panel, and tried to access testCommerce.abc, but still got a 404.

Can anyone explain why Wildfly does not check file extensions before deployment?  Is it because it expects an archive file and/or the file extension does not matter? And why, when deployment has been successful, I get a 404 in the browser for the .abc application? Is it due to changes coming in the directory paths when .war is changed to .abc? I've posted the Deployments section's image from the Admin Panel for verification.

[image: wildfly file extension test]

[image: wildfly 404 page]

Comment: It just deploys to the server, but does not register it as webcontent. If you look at the serverlog it just gives you `JBAS018559: Deployed ...` when you deploy a war you also get `JBAS017534: Registered web context ...`

Comment: Okay. That explains why it gives a 404. But how does it get deployed in the first place? Is Wildfly smart enough to recognize a WAR irrespective of its extension? Doesn't the file extension make the file recognizable to any program in the first place? How come Wildfly is able to deploy any off-the-top-of-my-head extension file?

Comment: I guess it tries to unzip and look for a deployment descriptor. If it does not find one it is not registerd as web context.

Comment: Well I simply changed the file extension, not the content. If it was able to deploy it, I'm assuming it must have unzipped the file. And the deployment descriptor had to be there.